# how do I select in css so the items appears in hover state In entire page(mega menu)

Tags: css, hover, megamenu

[image: example see image]; that end-result I want to reach.[1]]

How to select in CSS that all list items appears only in hover state and in four columns-width 960px; (see image above). I don't know which tag to select in this case, see HTML below.

```
<div class="categories">
  <li>
    <a href="#">All categories</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use this:

1. Change the `id="sub-menu"` to `class="sub-menu"`, as `id` is not meant to be duplicated.
2. Give the following initial CSS: `.sub-menu {display: none;}`.
3. Do not nest `<li>` inside `<div>`. Change it to `<ul>`

**Working Fiddle**

```css
.categories li .sub-menu {display: none;}
.categories li:hover .sub-menu {display: block;}
```

```html
<ul class="categories">
  <li>
    <a href="#">All categories</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All categories</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Put in your class categories that line:**

```
visibility: hidden;
```

**And make that class in your CSS code:**

```
.categories:hover{
visibility:visible;
}
```

This it will make it hidden but but still takes up space.
Useful links : [Hover](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) [Visibility](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp). If you want to NOT take space you can try make it position static.
I hope this works.

Comment: Link for the Position Static http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: Kindly do not use `w3schools` as a reference. See http://w3fools.com for more info.